# if condition not working in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, smarty

i am using sencha touch for developing a mobile application. In the list, i am using Css to change the color of the values greater than 0 (to green) and lesser than 0(to red). For values less than 1000  the color changes but for the values greater than 1000 the color is not changing.. please help

my code

```
<div class="amt_txt">
    <tpl if="Amount &gt;= 0">
        <span class='drill'>
            <strong>
                <span class='dollartxt'>
                    $
                </span>
                {Amount}
            </strong>
        </span>
    <tpl elseif="Amount &lt;=0">
        <span class="YldDataColor3">
            <span class='dollartxt'>
                $
            </span>
            {Amount}
        </span>
    </tpl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a function for this:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div class="amt_txt">' +
        '<span class="classForBold{[this.classChooser(values)]}">' + // <<--- here is the call
            '<span class='dollartxt'>' +
                '$' +
            '</span>' +
            '{Amount}' +
        '</span>' +
    '</div>',
    classChooser: function(values) { // <<--- here is the function
        var amount = value.Amount, returnValue;

        switch (amount) {
            case < 1000:
                returnValue = ' drill'; // important leading blank
                break;
            case < 0:
                returnValue =  ' YldDataColor3';
                break;
            default:
                returnValue =  '';
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
)
```